# Understanding and finding the principal solution of ODE with non-constant matrix

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a system of differential equations $ \dot{x}= A(t)x $ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, the matrix $A(t) \in GL(\mathbb{R}^2)$ has eigenvalues $\alpha_1(t)=t, \; \alpha_2(t)=0$. I am supposed to find the determinat of princial matrix solution $\Pi(t,t_0)$ in $t=1,\; t_0=0$, i.e. $\det(\Pi(1,0))$.

Now, I know how to proceed when the matrix is constant because then I have an explicit formula for a solution but I don´t know what to do when the matrix and its eigenvalues depend on t. I would appreciate any kind of help and explanations.

Comment: If $0$ is an eigenvalue, $A(t) \ne GL(\mathbb R^2)$.  By definition $GL$ means nonsingular matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if $U(t)$ is a  matrix solution of $\dfrac{dU}{dt} = A(t) U(t)$,
$$\dfrac{d}{dt} \det(U(t)) = \text{trace}(A(t)) \det(U(t))$$